# How to setup an openldap addressbook for thunderbird secure s/mime email ?

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, thunderbird, smime

I want to setup an ldap server that will hold an addressbook of users their emails their smime certificates.
I want to use this ldap server as an addressbook in thunderbird and/or other mail clients but thunderbird is preferred.
I would like to be able to import contacts from this addressbook(one or all) including their s/mime certs so that i can email any and/or all of them securely . both signed and encrypted.
And basically when another new user is created on the server, everyone can get his identity and send him/her signed or encrypted messages.

So far I've struggled with trying to add userSMIMECertificate fields to entries in the ou=People but to no avail - thunderbird can search for them, doesn't list them all by default but matches search patterns, however there's no smime import or anything like that.

Comment: This question would require a whole tutorial to answer.  Setting up LDAP is a lot of work.  With luck someone can give you a pointer to a tutorial somewhere.  Otherwise you'll need to come back with a more focused question after performing the initial setup yourself.

Comment: i have an openldap virtual appliance and a few test accounts setup.
I already have thunderbird setup to use ldap for fetching contacts and it can search by name for instance in the contacts pane and it receives correct email addresses for matching results. ie 'jo' matches john doe and joe willson so i can mail both of them. the problem is i want to fetch their smimes too.

Comment: hmmm nothing :( ?